# Does VSCode have a hotkey/shortcut for "toggle replace", switching between "find" and "replace" mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Visual Studio Code has a search and replace widget with a little dropdown button that toggles between one-line search mode and two-line replace mode. If you hover the pointer over it there's a tooltip saying "Toggle Replace".

[image: search mode] [image: replace mode]

Almost every function I've ever wanted a hotkey for in VSCode has had one, and I can find them by looking in the View/Command Palette... menu. But there doesn't seem to be a hotkey for this one. Unless it's confusingly named or perhaps built-in and hence not listed?

I am aware that there are separate keys for "Find" and "Replace" and that the first one takes me to the top line or only line if the box is in "Find mode" and the second takes me to the bottom line, and puts the box in "Replace mode" if it is currently in "Find mode".

But sometimes I just want it to be back in Find mode when I don't intend to do any replacing, but I want to do it without having to use mouse/trackpad since I touchtype and my fingers are on the keyboard.

I know I don't *need* it but I keep *wanting* it. I know it's very minor.

Is there a way to put the Find and Replace widget back into single-line "Find" mode from the keyboard?

(I'm using the Mac version if that makes any difference.)

Comment: from Find to Replace is `Ctrl+H` and `Ctrl+F` moves back to find box

Comment: @rioV8 that doesn't work for me. I'm on Mac and added that to the question.

Comment: When I do what rioV8 suggests, it doesn't *toggle* the lines as the question wants.  It just moves the focus around.  Helpful, but not quite what is being asked for.

Comment: @TimothyG. for me I thought it did nothing, but it seems to be same as backspace. I haven't got it to affect focus yet.

Comment: This is what I mean - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJnxU.gif

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce that.

Comment: replace `Ctrl` with `Cmd`

Comment: @rioV8 already tried that. It's a standard Mac shortcut to hide the current app.

Comment: What is the `Replace` command bound to in your Keyboard Shortcuts?  Use that instead of `Cmd+H` if that is bound to something else.  It toggles focus back and forth - same command - between the Find and Replace inputs.  Yes, it doesn't close the Replace input, but it is the same single keybinding, no reversing steps, just one step.

Comment: @Mark: Ah yes. It's `⌥` `⌘` `F` and it does indeed work as rioV8 describes.

Comment: I can just keep hitting Ctrl+H (or option+command+F for you) to toggle focus between the two inputs.  You don't need to switch between Ctrl+F and Ctrl+H.

Comment: oops yes I meant it's as @TimothyG. describes (-:

Comment: the function of the dialog by pressing `Enter` depends on the box your in, it is not what is visible, see the when clause in the keybind dialog for functions of `Enter`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*From the keyboard*, yes.  If you use your <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys (<kbd>Space</kbd> also works instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>), you can control this window.  Note the blue outline around the selected control.

When you first open the Find box, it is focused in the text field of the text you want to find.  If you do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will move the focus to the arrow that toggles the replace line.  Simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you can open the replace textbox line.  You can basically do this in reverse to then toggle the replace line to be hidden again.

[image]

Comment: Nice! `Space` works as well as `Enter` too.

Answer (score 1):

When you first open the Find box, it is focused in the text field of the text you want to find. If you are using a mac do `Shift` + `option` + `Tab`, it will move the focus to the arrow that toggles the replace line.